# How to get all available customer group from magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

I want to fetch all the customer group which is used in the tier price e.g All Group, Not Logged In, Wholesaler,General etc.

I have code on my extended controller and its path is company\TierPriceImport\Model\Convert\Adapter\product.php

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($this->_group_list as $group) 
{
       if (strtolower($group['label'])) 
       {
         echo $group['label']
         break;
       }
 }
```

it only shows me General and Wholesale. However, i need to display complete list of group name which are available in magneto instead of just two.

Please help me to get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->_group_list = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
```

Comment: thanks it works but small issue is it not gives **ALL GROUPS** rest of all group information i get

Comment: @Jalpesh "All Groups" is not a group, it is ... well ... all the groups. It's an option for applying something to ... again ... all groups